# Error in executing an OleDbCommand.. "Must declare the scalar variable "@MaxID"."

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

```
private void AddValue(string strValue)

{

      //get the maximum id for Lists first

      int MaxID = DataOperations.ReturnMaxIDInATable("Lists", connString);
      int iSqlStatus = 0;
      string query = "INSERT INTO Lists(ID, ListName, ListValue) 
         VALUES(@MaxID, @ListName, @ListValue)";

      MaxID++;

      OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
      OleDbCommand dbComm = new OleDbCommand();

      dbComm.Parameters.Clear();
      try
      {
                dbComm.CommandText = query;
                dbComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                OleDbParameter IDParam = new OleDbParameter();
                IDParam.ParameterName = "@MaxID";
                IDParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.BigInt;
                IDParam.Value = MaxID;
                dbComm.Parameters.Add(IDParam);

                dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListName", ListName);
                dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListValue", strValue);
                dbComm.Connection = dbConn;
                DataAccess.HandleConnection(dbConn);

                iSqlStatus = Convert.ToInt16(dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery());

                //Now check the status
                if (iSqlStatus != 0)
                {
                    //DO your failed messaging here
                    //return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do your success work here
                    //dbComm.
                    //return true;
                }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error inserting value in "
                                            + ListName + ","
                                            + strValue);
                //return false;
      }
      finally
      {
                DataAccess.HandleConnection(dbConn);
      }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389591/dotnet-oledbparameters-name-obsession

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use **question marks** for the parameters when executing SQL through the *OleDbCommand* (while *SqlCommand* uses @). Example:

```
INSERT INTO Lists (ID, ListName, ListValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

You only need to Add the Parameters in the order that they appear in the SQL.

Comment: Yea for OleDb, it is the order that counts, not the names

Comment: But not only the order, but the *question marks* that represent "parameter" for OleDb.

Comment: I've been using @ for the parameter name in other parts of the code and it works so changing it in ? should be moot. But I would try other wise. Also the order I think doesn't affect but I would also try.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you include the clause "DECLARE" in the start of query, will work:

```
string query = "DECLARE @MaxID as bigint, "+
                      " @ListName as Varchar(100), "+
                      " @ListValue As Varchar(100) " +
        " INSERT INTO Lists(ID, ListName, ListValue) " +
            " VALUES(@MaxID, @ListName, @ListValue)"
```

Furthermore, the right solution is change your driver to SQLClient and OracleClient. OleDb is not recomended for be used with SQL 2005 and above.

Answer (score -2):

The following fragment should read:

```
IDParam.ParameterName = "MaxID";
IDParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.BigInt;
IDParam.Value = MaxID;
dbComm.Parameters.Add(IDParam);

dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("ListName", ListName);
dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("ListValue", strValue);
```

Comment: It don't solve the problem for OleDbCommand. Even, it haven't any effect on SqlCommand.

Comment: I tried BigInt before and it didn't work. But haven't tried not using a prefix for the Parameter names. I would try this one also.

Comment: No prefixes on the parameters don't work either. Any more solutions in mind?

Answer (score -2):

This seemed to do the trick..

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Lists(ID, ListName, ListValue) 
         VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}')", MaxID, ListName, strValue);
```

Although I have reservations about it like what if I need to add a date value?