# Paramterising an SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, parameterized

I've been working with paramaterising my SQL statements lately, and have managed to do so for my `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries. However, I am struggling to do so with `SELECT`... Is anybody able to help me? I feel it's because I'm using `OleDbDataAdapter`, rather than `OleDbCommand`?

```
    Public Shared Function getPerson(ByVal personID As Integer, m_cn As OleDbConnection)

    Dim Dt As New DataTable

    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE personID = " & personID, m_cn)

    Da.Fill(Dt)

    Return Dt

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.71).aspx) has the parameters for the SQL statement (or stored procedure) used to select records:

```
Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE personID = @PersonID", m_cn)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = personID
    Da.Fill(Dt)
End Using
```

I suggest to not reuse the connection(or make it even static/shared) since that can cause various  issues. Instead create, open and use it wherever you need it, so in this method, best by using the `Using` statement to ensure that it gets closed even in case of an error.

Comment: Hi Tim, I put this statement between the lines `Dim Da As New OleDbAdapter` and `Da.Fill(Dt)` (after taking out the original SQL line), and I get an error saying `Variable 'Da' hides a variable in an enclosing block` in `Using Da`... Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe: you don't need to declare the adapter anymore since it's created in the `Using`statement. It is closed and disposed at the the end of it. All you want to do with it belongs into the `Using`. Remember to use the `Using`-statement for anything that implements `IDisposable`(with few exceptions like `DataTable`/`DataSet`) which don't hold unmanaged resources.

Comment: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@PersonID".' is the new error after changing it this way?

Comment: @Joe: have you seen that i've modified your query?

Comment: Yes, the one I copied and pasted directly from your answer (Just done it again now), still returns the same error

Comment: @joe: you have also added this line: `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = personID`? Maybe you need to use the question mark syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5870248/284240 because named parameters are not supported by your DB

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I had added that line and it was just the question mark syntax that was causing it to fail, so thank you for your help!

Comment: You have `SqlDbType` rather than `OleDbType`

Comment: @Plutonix: fixed, but since he can't use named parameters there's still something to fix above

Comment: Tim - doesn't your example run counter to your recommendation to not reuse a connection? m_cn seems to be a reused connection to me.

Comment: My suggestion is to create the connection here by using the using statement. I have just left out the code